# I am getting characters rather than words when I alert an array reference

Tags: javascript

On the first alert(array[0]) I get a full word. On the next alert after the loop, I get only a character with each reference. I found a similar question on here, but there wasn't an answer with it.

```
var listNumbers = document.getElementById("someNames").getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(var i = 0; i<listNumbers.length; i++) {
        z = (listNumbers[i].innerHTML);
        array = z.split(" ");
        alert(array[0]);
        firstArray = firstArray + '"' + array[0] + '"' + ", ";
        lastArray = lastArray + '"' + array[1] + '"' + ", ";
        phoneArray = phoneArray + '"' + array[2] + '"' + ", ";

    }   
    alert(firstArray[1]);
```

Comment: can you show your html?

Comment: Whats the value of `listNumbers[i].innerHTML`?

Comment: <ul id = "someNames">
 <li>David Brodersen 702-651-0000</li>
 <li>Naser Heravi 702-651-0001</li>
 <li>Shellie Keller 702-651-7638</li>
 <li>Demitri Mavroidis 702-702-7027</li>
 <li>Shawn Mapleton 702-702-7028</li>
 <li>Charleston Tutorial 702-651-5732</li>
 <li>Charleston Library 702-651-5723</li>
 <li>Charleston Info 702-651-5000</li>
 <li>Cheyenne Info 702-651-4000</li>
  </ul>

Comment: The first alert shows up with "David". The second alert shows up with only "D".

Comment: Works just fine https://jsfiddle.net/31b8278L/. The `alert` after the loop gives you `D` because you're accessing the second character in the `firstArray` string. BTW, using `Array` in a variable holding a string adds confusion.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code (and took out the firstArray, lastArray, and phoneArray lines, which aren't defined in the sample) and it seems to work as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1):

You are building your `firstArray` variable as a string, not an array. When you access a string with `[0]`, you will get the character at that position in the string, not a whole word.

If you want to be able to access words, you need to declare it as an array and use `.push()` to add words to it.

```
var listNumbers = document.getElementById("someNames").getElementsByTagName("li");
var arrayOfFirstNames = [];
var arrayOfLastNames = [];
var arrayOfPhoneNumbers = [];
for(var i = 0; i<listNumbers.length; i++) {
    z = (listNumbers[i].innerHTML);
    array = z.split(" ");
    alert(array[0]);
    arrayOfFirstNames.push('"' + array[0] + '"');
    arrayOfLastNames.push('"' + array[1] + '"');
    arrayOfPhoneNumbers.push('"' + array[2] + '"');

}   
alert(arrayOfFirstNames[0]);
```

I don't have your HTML so I havn't tested this code, but it should do the job if all you want is 3 arrays of first names, last names and phone numbers that you can access using square bracket notation.

Comment: millerbr: Thank you! .push works perfectly. U da bomb!

Comment: I clicked the arrow to the left of your answer. Is that what you mean?

Comment: The tick icon underneath that - that marks this answer as correct so that anyone who finds this question later can see it has an answer